# How get post value in pagination

Tags: php, sql, pagination

I am working on search functionality with pagination in php.Below is my code but whenever I click on next link the search query is not taking variable which is passed through POST.
Can you please help me..

```
searchstr=$_POST['q'];
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['searchchar']=$searchstr;
$rec_limit=3;
$connection=connection();
$searchstr=$_REQUEST['q'];
$sql="Select count(*) from  FIMTRN_Memorial where FirstName like '%".$_SESSION['searchchar']."%'";
echo$sql;
$result1=mysql_query($sql);
if(! $result1)
{
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result1,MYSQL_NUM );
$rec_count = $row[0];
echo$rec_count;
if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) )
{
    $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
    $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
}
else
{
    $page = 0;
    $offset = 0;
}
$left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);
$sql="Select * from  FIMTRN_Memorial where FirstName like '%".$_SESSION['searchchar']."%' limit $offset,$rec_limit";
echo$sql;
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rec_num=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($rec_num>0)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    { 
        $fname=$row['FirstName'];
        $image=$row['ProfileImagePath'];
        $about=$row['About'];
        $url=$row['CustomURL'];
        $DOB=$row['DOB'];
        $DOD=$row['DOD'];
?>
<div class="search">
    <p class="content"><img src="<?php echo $image;?>" style="border:1px solid red;width:100px;height:100px;" /></p>
<div class="content"><p>
<?php 
    echo "<a href=\"$url;\" target=\"_blank\">$fname</a>";
?>
    <p>(<?php echo date("Y",strtotime($DOB));?>-<?php echo date("Y", strtotime($DOD));?>)</p>
    </p><p><?php echo$about?></p>
</div>
</div>
<?php
    }
    if( $page > 0 & $left_rec > $rec_limit)
    {

        $last = $page - 2;
        echo "<a href=\"?page=$last\">Previous Records</a> |";
        echo "<a href=\"?page=$page\">Next  Records</a>";
    }
    else if( $page == 0 & $rec_count>$rec_limit )
    {     
        echo "<a href=\"?page=$page\">Next  Records</a>";
    }
    else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit & $rec_count>$rec_limit )
    {
        $last = $page - 2;
        echo "<a href=\"?page=$last\">Previous Records</a>";
    }
}
else
{
     echo"No memorial found.Please try with other name.";
}



enter code here

?>
```

Comment: You cant pass value from one page to another on url,You can send the search string using $_GET

Comment: Please remove unwanted `\`` from code and proper align your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple problems in your code.

First:

You are using the `$_GET` variable incorrectly. You have `$_GET{'page'}`, but you should be using it the same way as the`$_POST` variable, like this: `$_GET['page']`

Second:

You are interpreting the idea of POSTing and clicking links incorrectly.  What you need to make with your next and previous buttons are a hidden form that has all the other variables you need.  For example, the simplest way that won't involve changing a lot of your other code:

```
if( $page > 0 & $left_rec > $rec_limit)
{
    $last = $page - 2;
    // Previous button form
    echo "<form action='?page=$last' method='POST'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='q' value='" . $_POST['q'] . "' />"; // This will be a field that saves information but won't appear on the page (though a user could see it if they view source)
    echo "<input type='submit' value='Previous Records' />";
    echo "</form>";
    echo " | "; // The delimiting character you were using, you'll need to style the input type='submit's to look more like a link if that's what you are going for
    // Next button form
    echo "<form action='?page=$page' method='POST'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='q' value='" . $_POST['q'] . "' />"; // This will be a field that saves information but won't appear on the page (though a user could see it if they view source)
    echo "<input type='submit' value='Next  Records' />";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

This method will keep your variables in the request.  Using a link essentially resets the $_POST variable.  There are a ton of other possible solutions, but this is one will require the least amount of work to modify your example.

Comment: Perhaps not a real "problem", you set `$searchstr` twice, once to `$_POST['q']` and once to `$_REQUEST['q']`.

Comment: Thanks for reply.If I remove $_REQUET['q'] also its not working.

Comment: Hi...I am using ' quote in search string then its not passin to next page..can any body help me..thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are creating sorting and searching functionality than I will suggest you to use `$_SESSION` variable rather than `$_POST` or `$_GET` it will help you manage your grid/data very well.