# pagination in search page with search text starting with single quote in php

Tags: php, pagination

I am working on pagination on search result.I referred below link and I am not able to pass value when search text starts with single quote..
[How get post value in pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908332/how-get-post-value-in-pagination).
Can you please help me..
thanks

Comment: answered.but not working when search string starts with single quote..

Answer (score 0):

This is because the single quote is embedded into the literal string `$sql`. It halts the query, and this is dangerous because a hacker can do what is called SQL Injection -> https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/ .

Anyway, the mysql extension has been deprecated, meaning it is no longer supported and maintained. You have two easy options: mysqli or PDO. I personally recommend using PDO -> https://www.php.net/PDO . It will be easy to convert your code.

With PDO you can bind your input to certain fields:

```
$sql="Select count(*) from  FIMTRN_Memorial where FirstName like :search";
$sql = $database->prepare($sql);
$sql->execute(array(":search" => "%".$_SESSION['searchchar']."%"));

$result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I hope I could help!

**UPDATE:**
With the above parameterized query, your search string cannot contain a percentage sign, as this will act as a wild-card character.

**UPDATE 2:**
I don't know if you noticed that `$_GET{'page'}` is meant to be `$_GET['page']` in the previous answer.